# Call freemarker macro from different file

Tags: freemarker

I have situation like this. I have folder `a` and inside it I have `a.ftl` and folder `b`. Inside folder `b` there is `b.ftl`. in `b.ftl` I have `[#macro macroName param1]...[/#macro]` How to call macro from file `a`? I have intellij idea warning. I saw this link https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206196939-Getting-Intellij-to-pick-up-Freemarker-macros so I tried to place

```
[#-- @implicitly included --]
[#-- @ftlroot "" --]
```

to the top of the `a.ftl` but it doesn't work. I was looking into freemarker docs http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_macro.html but there is example just with calling macro from the same file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `<#import "/b/b.ftl" as b>` (where the last `b` can be any variable name), and then you can call the macro like `<@b.macroName ...>`. Putting commonly needed macros/functions/values into a template that's `#import`-ed in other templates is common best practice.

You can also use `<#include "/b/b.ftl">` in `/a/a.ftl`, and then you can just use `<@macroName ...>` (no namespace prefix like `b.`). The common use case of `#include` is however printing common output, as it executes the whole `a.ftl`, each time it's `#include`-d. If `a.ftl` only contains macro definitions and other such assignments that might not matter.

Imports and includes can also be executed automatically in the topmost template. For that, see the `auto_imports` (`Configuration.setAutoImports`) and `auto_includes` (`Configuration.setAutoIncludes`) configuration settings.

See also: http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_namespace.html

Comment: I have used solution with import, thank you for help.